# label not updated in System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadabortexception

In my page i am trying to download file. THe file is downloaded successfully but i get System.Threading.ThreadAbortException. So i handled that in my try Catch Block and set the error lable to blank but it doesnt get updated in page.

```
        catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {
            lblErrorMsg.Text = "dfdf";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorMsg.Text = "Error while processing you request :<br> Erorr Description : " + ex.Message;
        }
```

This is my Write file function

```
  public static void WriteFile(string nameOfFile, string fileContent, HttpResponse writer)
    {
        writer.ClearHeaders();
        writer.ClearContent();

        writer.ContentType = "text/xml";
        writer.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nameOfFile);
        writer.Write(fileContent);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.End();
    }
```

Can someone tell why label is not set to blank even though it comes under the Catch Block of system.thread.threadabortexceptiopn when i debug code ?

Answer (score 0):

ThreadAbortException happens because you close the Response prematurely, by calling End() method of Response object. 
This also explains why it's too late to write on the page content. It's not a very annoying error but it would be better to handle it cleanly.

Just check these answers [Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception) or [How to Avoid Response.End() "Thread was being aborted" Exception during the Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce) and other answers related to Response and ThreadAbortException to understand it and handle properly by writing a better code for file download, according your usage.

Also please note that doesn't make a great sense to have both a completely rewritten Response stream for a page and some content on it, like a Label.

Comment: i am not writing any content on label. Just writing exception on label. Links in Your answer not helping me :(  can you give me specific solution

Comment: Also as you can see in my code that i am not doing response.redirect

Comment: First question : you are explicitly emptying the Response content to replace it by your download, and despite this there is a control on your form and you try to write something on it. That's not logic. Second question : have you read the answer of user3412640 on my second link ? I told you the problem is the call to End() method of your Response.

Comment: The first link about Redirect was for the explanation of what happens, not for a direct fix.