# How to return custom error page without ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, threadabortexception

In Mono MVC5 controller code below is used to return custom error page:

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id, string product)
    {
       ....
        if (productNotFound) {
            // http://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/7/2/mvc-custom-error-pages
            Response.Clear();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            Response.Write(product + " product not exists");
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            Response.End();
            return null;
        }
```

Aftersome time this causes ThreadAbortException which can catched in Application_Error.
It looks like thread continues to run until timeout is reached.

How to fix this so that exception does not occur?

Answers in SO require web.config modification and lot of code in different places.

I'm looking for a simple way to return custom error page without web.config modificationin MVC5.

How to terminate thred in controller or is there other way to avoid exception.
Exceptions are logged from Applicaion_Error and it would be nive if log file does not containt such exceptions.

Exception stack trace:

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Thread:Abort_internal (System.Threading.InternalThread,object)
  at System.Threading.Thread.Abort (System.Object stateInfo) [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono-4.4.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs:477 
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.End () [0x0001c] in /usr/local/src/mono-4.4.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpResponse.cs:637 
  at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.End () [0x00000] in /usr/local/src/mono-4.4.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpResponseWrapper.cs:275 
  at MyApp.Store.Controllers.StoreController.Details (System.String id, System.String product) <0x414f9210 + 0x0026b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:lambda_method (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Closure,System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase,object[])
  at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase controller, System.Object[] parameters) <0x40dee7d0 + 0x0002d> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) <0x40dec2c0 + 0x000ff> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) <0x40dec260 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod () <0x40dec230 + 0x00025> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39 (IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) <0x40dec080 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Web.Mvc.Async.EndInvokeDelegate`2[System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+ActionInvocation,System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]:invoke_TResult_IAsyncResult_TState (System.IAsyncResult,System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker/ActionInvocation)
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResult`2[TResult,TState].CallEndDelegate (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x40dec000 + 0x0006a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper+WrappedAsyncResultBase`1[TResult].End () <0x40debd80 + 0x00053> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult] (IAsyncResult asyncResult, System.Object tag) <0x40debc30 + 0x0003b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x418f4fc0 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d () <0x41984f10 + 0x0007a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker+AsyncInvocationWithFilters+<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f () <0x40ddbd70 + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Maybe it is `Response.End` faults...check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce

Comment: Thank you. It looks like End() causes it. I changed code to `Response.Clear();
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                Response.Write(product + " no product");
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                              Response.Flush();
                Response.SuppressContent = true;
                HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();` as descibed in https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/May/26/Ending-a-Response-without-ResponseEnd-Exceptions

Comment: I am glad to help :)