# C# HttpHandler crashes IIS - but only in Release mode with optimizations on

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httphandler

I have a HttpHandler which looks like this:

```
public class GoodIISHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside finally block");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable => true;
}
```

It works great! Except when compiled in Release mode with optimizations enabled and then executed (on Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8 with .NET 4.5.2). Then it crashes IIS.

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/1592535739/ROOT/HttpHandlerApp
>
> Process ID: 648
>
> Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>
> Message: Thread was being aborted.
>
> StackTrace:    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>
> at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

and

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.0.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108835
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17366, time stamp: 0x554d4531
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x000000000004aea8
>
> Faulting process id: 0x288
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d1ec2c7db735a6
>
> Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: bb7471fa-581f-11e6-93f1-00155d461b1c
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

I have narrowed the issue down to a particular bit of IL which changes when optimization is enabled/disabled.

Here is the IL for `ProcessRequest` which does not crash IIS:

```
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance void  ProcessRequest(class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext context) cil managed
{
  // Code size       30 (0x1e)
  .maxstack  1
  .try
  {
    .try
    {
      IL_0000:  ldarg.1
      IL_0001:  callvirt   instance class [System.Web]System.Web.HttpResponse [System.Web]System.Web.HttpContext::get_Response()
      IL_0006:  callvirt   instance void [System.Web]System.Web.HttpResponse::End()
      IL_000b:  leave.s    IL_0010

    }  // end .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
    {
      IL_000d:  pop
      IL_000e:  leave.s    IL_0010

    }  // end handler
    IL_0010:  leave.s    IL_001d

  }  // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_0012:  ldstr      "Inside finally block"
    IL_0017:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_001c:  endfinally
  }  // end handler
  IL_001d:  ret
} // end of method GoodIISHandler::ProcessRequest
```

To make IIS crash, change line 19 to

```
        IL_000e:  leave.s    IL_001d
```

This change makes the nested catch block exit directly to the method return instruction without visiting the single instruction remaining in the try block of the try..finally.

My hypothesis is that the crash relates to the magic auto-rethrow behaviour of `ThreadAbortException` (one of which `context.Response.End()` will throw) and how the CLR and/or IIS and/or ASP.NET manages that; and so when the optimised IL exits from the catch block directly to the return instruction, some hypothetical abort reset magic which the CLR/IIS/ASP.NET slotted in at `IL_0010` gets missed out and the ThreadAbortException takes down the whole of IIS.

There are clues scattered around the internet about this behaviour (e.g. [these msdn docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception(v=vs.110).aspx) state `ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will automatically be raised again at the end of the catch block.` and [this blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2009/03/13/managed-code-and-asynchronous-exception-hardening/) mentions `... notably ASP.NET, even aborts individual threads routinely without unloading the domain. They backstop the ThreadAbortExceptions, call ResetAbort on the thread and reuse it or return it to the CLR ThreadPool.`) but I cannot find anything concrete about the mechanism.

So I guess my question is: what is going on here? Have I really discovered a CLR or IIS or ASP.NET bug to do with this thread abort mechanism being defeated by an IL optimisation?

---

Fully scripted repro can be found at https://github.com/jamezor/HttpHandlerRepro for anyone interested.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework did you use? 4.6.0 is known to have some issues, and you should disable RyuJIT to workaround some.

Comment: We are running with .NET 4.5.2 so cannot blame 4.6 unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **Response.End()** to stop processing the request, it's better to use **HttpApplication.CompleteRequest()**. Take a look at these posts:

- [How to Avoid Response.End() “Thread was being aborted” Exception during the Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce)
- [Is Response.End() considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087777/is-response-end-considered-harmful/3917180#3917180) .

Comment: That may be true, but then still `Response.End()` should not crash the worker process.

Comment: Yeah, that's the true :-/. Ok and have you checked Rapid Fail Proctection settings for the application pool in IIS? Are there default values? Any other interesting event in the event log?

Comment: We've migrated 200k lines from Delphi.Net to C#, Response.End() is used liberally unfortunately. But in any case, with only one tiny IL change (or just compiling without optimisations) IIS works as expected and does not crash which to me rules out any possible configuration issues. And the only events in the event log are shown in the question, no others appear.