# "Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll" when using Response.Redirect()

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, mscorlib, threadabortexception

In an OnClick method for a button in an ASP.NET web form I have a call to Response.Redirect() which causes the system to abort the thread with the error message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
```

There's a few questions similar to this on here, using their solutions I changed:

```
Response.Redirect("~/UI/Home.aspx");
```

to

```
Response.Redirect("~/UI/Home.aspx", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

However I am still getting the same problem. Using the debugger I ran through the code and it all executed successfully until I called Response.Redirect();.

**OnClick Function**

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SiteUser s = null;
        try
        {
            string email = txtEmail.Text;
            string pwd = txtPwd.Text;
            s = DBConnection.login(email, pwd);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
            lblLoginError.Text = "Error logging in.";
        }
        if (s != null)
        {
            Session["UserSession"] = s;
            Response.Redirect("~/UI/Home.aspx", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoginError.Text = "User not found. Please check your details and try again.";
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

Comment: `Response.Redirect()` *really shouldn't* be throwing that exception when given the `false` argument...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Response.Redirect causes System.Threading.ThreadAbortException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777105/why-response-redirect-causes-system-threading-threadabortexception)

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Very similar issue but it isn't resolved by the solutions there.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this problem in the past.  In theory, if you use this code, it shouldn't happen:

```
Response.Redirect(url, false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

That being said, I still got these sometimes, which is really surprising. I am guessing that it sometimes occurs in the presence of an active `finally` block to signal the code to start cleaning itself up, although that doesn't seem to be the case for you.

The best fix I could come up with is to catch the error and ignore it.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SiteUser s = null;
        try
        {
            string email = txtEmail.Text;
            string pwd = txtPwd.Text;
            s = DBConnection.login(email, pwd);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
            lblLoginError.Text = "Error logging in.";
        }
        if (s != null)
        {
            Session["UserSession"] = s;
            Response.Redirect("~/UI/Home.aspx", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            lblLoginError.Text = "User not found. Please check your details and try again.";
        }
    }
    catch(System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
    {
        //Do nothing.  The exception will get rethrown by the framework when this block terminates.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this doesn't seem to fix the problem - it is still just reloading the login page.

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an issue that I had caused by redirecting back if the session didn't contain a specific element in the target page, and in this instance it didn't! The exception is still thrown but no longer causing visible problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I Resolve this using

```
Response.Redirect(.....)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
```

Reference: [How to Avoid Response.End() "Thread was being aborted" Exception during the Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce)